# Closed Opera window with tabs, trying to get them back from other window still open

Tags: browser, tabs, opera, opera-10

I accidentally closed an Opera window with many important tabs open only to find out that another window is still active with one tab open. Closing it will overwrite the saved tabs of the other window, which I want to recover.

I need to recover the window with "many tabs" if possible. I didn't yet close the window with the one tab open, hopefully that prevents overwriting the saved settings.

How do I retrieve, now that Opera is still active, the tabs of the closed window? I.e., where would Opera normally store these tabs when it closes a window? Can I prevent it from overwriting the saved state of "many tabs" with the current "one tab"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you haven't closed and re-started Opera, there's a button at the top-right corner which used to look like a trash can, now looks like <strike>an arrow curving around an X</strike> a bin with a recycle symbol - clicking it will pop up a list of recently closed tabs *and windows*. Just click the item for the window you closed.

Also, in future, always quit via the menu File -> Exit, rather than closing windows :)

Comment: Silly me, great! I hoped there was something simple like that. Using Firefox mostly, I don't have a "window recovery". Glad I didn't fully close Opera while waiting for an answer. All's recovered, thanks!

Comment: PS: File > Exit keeps windows *and* tabs?

Comment: Yes, so long as your Startup preference is "Continue from last time".

Comment: Hugh: Actually, I think it may do that anyway -- it puts them in an autosaved.win file.  However, if your Startup preference is something else, it will ignore that file and overwrite it when you restart Opera.  The reason the distinction is important is that you can move/rename the autosaved.win file while Opera is not running, and then load it manually once you start Opera.

Answer (score -2):

You can't get them. They're gone.

Next time you start Opera, or, in the window that remains for that matter, you only get the closed tabs from *that* window.